# A Dummy's guide Offline install of NPM Packages Windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I am new to NPM and NodeJS. I am curently following a tutorial on Pluralsight using MongoDB, Express, Express Generator, View Enginge Swig and Mongoose.
I have downloaded and installed MongoDB and NodeJS both on a computer having internet access, and on a server with no access.

I dont't really seem to grasp how I can get these packages from the online computer to the server with no internet access. The articles I find seems to assume a whole lot more experience in the realm of NPM than I currently have.

If someone could write an 1-2-3 guide on how to do it I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is not really the place for *"1-2-3 guides"* - you are much, much more likely to receive an answer if you ask a specific question. In your case it sounds like you are starting a little too big - why not start out getting used to Node and npm before getting involved with Mongo etc, and then post questions on specific issues you might be having with Node.

Lastly, getting files onto a machine with no internet access is going to be same whether you are writing Node or VB6. If there is no network access at all you will need to use some form of physical media.

Comment: Is this not really a comment?

Comment: Yeah, I toyed with making this a comment, and normally would for these kind of things, but it felt like there was a lot going on and that it would be more useful as an actual answer.